# Bot doesn't send emoji properly (Python 3.9.2 PyCharm 2021.1)

Tags: python, discord.py, emoji

I was busy making my economy command in the my bot and I wanted to have a custom currency emoji. So I made one and I quickly put it into my code. Then, when I activated the bot, it only sent the emoji name! (No it didn't send the tiny code piece I used to identify the emoji, it just sent :currency_symbol:)

[image: Here is what has happened]

I need the emoji actually to show itself like an emoji.

What I did to make the emoji in PyCharm:

```
<a:currency_symbol:832506821675057173>
```

Code:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['bal'])
    async def balance(self, ctx):
        id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="CatsyBot Economy", description=f"{ctx.message.author}'s Balance", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.add_field(name="Bank", value="{} <a:currency_symbol:832506821675057173>".format(amounts[id]))
        if id in amounts:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send(embed="You do not have an account")
```

Comment: I think you should improve your question. The tag are about Python and pycharm, but you seems to discuss about some specific python library for some bot. I assume not IRC bots (and you have a `discord` in text). If you want to target the correct audience, you should tag correctly (nobody can read all new questions [too many per minute]). But also your question... you are assuming that we know what you are doing: do not do that! Explain better what you are doing, what you get, and what you expect.

Comment: A big coincidence! I just pressed the edit button

Comment: Add the correct tags! We look for questions by filtering the tags. (with Edit you can change the tags).

Comment: Like this is good?

Comment: There is nothing on your question about json, not about something specific to python-3.9. But there are many tags about discord. Check the tag which seems better. And use tag or describe on your question: what it is `discord` (not the service, but the specific library you are using), and what it is `commands` (same library? a different library?). Probably the version of such libraries is more relevant than the PyCharm or version of python.

Comment: Is the emoji animated? Are you sure you have used the correct name and id?

Comment: Emoji is not animated. Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If emoji is not animated, just write:
<currency_symbol:832506821675057173>
Code:

```
@commands.command(pass_context=True, aliases=['bal'])
    async def balance(self, ctx):
        id = str(ctx.message.author.id)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="CatsyBot Economy", description=f"{ctx.message.author}'s Balance", colour=discord.Colour.blue())
        embed.add_field(name="Bank", value="{} <currency_symbol:832506821675057173>".format(amounts[id]))
        if id in amounts:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send(embed="You do not have an account")
```

Comment: Or what he can try is just entering the emoji like "" instead of :name: if it is a standard emoji and no Discord-Special emoji (You can open the emoji window in windows with WIN+.)

Comment: It still doesn't work. Now it shows the whole code of the emoji.